# What is the functionality of "Reboot" type in the Wait-VM module

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v, cloud-init

"Wait-VM -Name $VMName -For Reboot"

There is no proper documentation available for this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wait-VM -For Reboot` checks the current uptime of the target VM, and simply waits until the uptime metric drops below what it was previously.

The equivalent in PowerShell would be:

```
$uptime = (Get-VM -Name $VMName).Uptime

do{
  # Wait
  Start-Sleep -Second 1

  # Fetch latest uptime metric
  $newestUptime = (Get-VM -Name $VMName).Uptime

  # Keep waiting until uptime dips below previous value
  $stillWaiting = $newestUptime -ge $uptime

  # Track new uptime value
  $uptime = $newestUptime
}while($stillWaiting)
```

---

> There is no proper documentation available for this module.

The module itself is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/?view=windowsserver2019-ps), but `Wait-VM` is conspicuously missing, and [has been for almost 3 years](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/issues/240) - I'd suggest providing feedback on the GitHub

Comment: Thanks Mathias for the solution